# .ASPNET.Cookies cookie is not creating during Azure AD authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am trying to integrate my web service to authenticate using Azure AD. During the applicaition startup, the login option works fine. After logging in, if i clear my cookies and try to login to the page, the page will be redirected to the Office365 login page, and after successful login using my office365 credentials, a cookie named, **.ASPNET.Cookies** will be created. But in my case, this cookie is not created.

[image]

The cookie is created only at the initial startup of the application. Once this cookie is deleted, its not created again.

I am using the code sample from github ( https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect ).

This code sample works fine, but using those code changes in my application doesn't works.

Thanks in Advance.

Dinesh.

Comment: What did you change for the code sample?